# Allowing users to update information without logging in (checksum)

Tags: checksum

this is the updatge my contact details (just contain the email for now)
https://website/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=78

I add the checksum and contact id
https://website/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=78&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}

When I send the test mailing it gets converted to
https://website/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=78&cs=fbdb7dc462db15bbcfb3e78b1b42c6ef_1632963321_168
(the id number is correctly populated

When I click the link (when loggedin) it works

When i click the link (without being loggin in) it redirects me to the homepage

I have also tried to use the example from here but that doesn't work either - just redirect me to homepage again https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/

Joomla!: [http://example.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&id=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

Can anyone advise why I'm being sent to the home page and not able to see the page/profile?

Joomla 3.10.2
CiviCRM 5.35.1

A million thanks in advance!

Comment: Do any other checksum links work?  If you're using checksums you might find this extension useful: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/checksum

Comment: +1 for the checksum extension, very helpful for this sort of thing. Also, I'd check permissions in your Joomla setup. I'm not familiar with Joomla, but in Drupal, you need to give public (anonymous) access to profile pages, otherwise the system thinks they're accessing a page they're not allowed.

Comment: Thanks so much @artfulrobot you sent me in the right direction. This is how I fixed the issue: 

1. Joomla > System > Global Configuration > CIVICRM

2. Click "public" to manage the permissions

3. Change profile edit to Allowed

Comment: @maxrebo797 great, glad it helped :-) - if you post that as an answer, you can accept it (in a few days). The benefit of this is that someone else looking can then see that there is a good answer, so it helps the usefulness of this site.